# List parent terms by vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to list only parent terms in order to rearrange the orders like **/admin/structure/taxonomy/vocabulary_name**. Given url have displayed all terms included child terms. I want to avoid term terms. So i've tried to create custom page.
I've tried below code but i can't make it work.

```
function test_menu() {
  $items['manage_category/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name'] = array(
   'title' => t('Manage category'),
   'page callback' => 'arep_manage_category',
   'page arguments' => array(1),
   'access arguments' => array('administer taxonomy'),
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
 return $items;
}

function arep_manage_category() {
  $category = arg(1);
  module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
  $taxonomy = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($category);
  $form = drupal_get_form('taxonomy_overview_terms', 'taxonomy_term', $taxonomy);
  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

I've tried to access this page by vocabulary name. How ot make it work? Is any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you add a cck field named **flag** for **levels** to your vocabulary when created, then after that when you import or add terms in this then fill flag value like **"My First Level"/"My Second Level"**. then you can fetch very easily like that..`

```
/* Get All States From Taxonomies */
  function get_taxonomy_by_flag($flag) {
       $VocabName = "Master Data";
          $myStateArray = array(0=>'-- Select --');
        $Vocabluary = get_vocabulary_by_name($VocabName);
         $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
          $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
->propertyCondition('vid', $Vocabluary->vid)    
->fieldCondition('field_flag', 'value', $flag, '=')    
->execute();
if(sizeof($entities)>0)
{       
  foreach($entities['taxonomy_term'] as $tid) {

    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid->tid);     
    $name=$term->name;
    $myStateArray[$term->field_code['und']['0']['value']] = $name;    
  }   
  return $myStateArray;     
}
else
{
    return 0;
 }    
}

    function get_vocabulary_by_name($vocabulary_name) {
        $vocabs = taxonomy_get_vocabularies(NULL);
         foreach ($vocabs as $vocab_object) {
          if ($vocab_object->name == $vocabulary_name) {
            return $vocab_object;
         }
      }
            return NULL;
      }
     call this function by flag name and you can easily get all parents. because i have used this for **State/District/Block/Village** purpose.
      get_taxonomy_by_flag('STATE');
```

hope this helps you lot...